# function.toString() in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, tostring

I don't understand how **f.toString** (*without calling it*) evaluate to returned result of that same function ?

```
function f(a){
    console.log(a + a);
    f.toString = function(){return a};// this part is       
//confusing.
    return f;
};

f(10) // 20
f(10)(20)// 20 40
```

Comment: I don't see where you're getting return value `10` from. `f(10)` gives `20` in the console for me.

Comment: If you remove the `toString` assignment, you get the same result, don't you? It does not do anything here. See: http://jsfiddle.net/AhCtn/.

Comment: We should differ between the function result and the console output as generated from inside the fnuction. The console will show f(10) to be 20, while the toString will result 10. Same for f(20) which will be 40 or 20 depending on the usage. console.log(f(10)) should show 20 10 in the log.

Comment: Maybe the `+` is confusing: it’s not just the string concatenation operator but also arithmetic addition operator. If you use `"" + a + a` instead you’ll get `1010` and `2020` instead. Maybe that’s what you were up to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact `f.toString` is not even called in your scenario. If you will remove this line  - result will be the same.

`f.toString()` will be called if you try to execute `console.log(f);`

Your results explained:

```
f(10) // 20
```

function `f` is called with argument `10`, and it prints to console `console.log(10 + 10);`

```
f(10)(20) // 20 40
```

first part as above, but `f` function also returns itself `return f;` , it means that second part `(20)` will be treated as call to the same function one more time and it prints `console.log(20 + 20);`

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted... seems to be all fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to use an object in a string context, then it will be converted to a string by calling it's `toString()` method.

See page 48 of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Comment: What you have typed - does not relate to the OP's question